# Coefficients of even powers

Tags: polynomials

Just a simple thought experiment I was running in my head.

Say I have a nonnegative even degree polynomial such as $f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$. Is it true that the coefficients of the even powers in f(x), namely, a, c and e have to non-negative as well?

My intuition says yes since that's the only way the polynomial can be non-negative in the interval $(0, 1]$, but I'm having trouble expressing this in a formal proof sort of way.

Comment: a and e are for sure. at x=0, x=-inf

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x^2-1)^2=x^4-2x^2+1$ is non-negative.

You will find some information about general results [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive%5fpolynomial), and [this](http://www.cs.newpaltz.edu/~fialkowl/files/nonnegative%5fpoly.pdf) looks as though it may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Note that an even degree polynomial is negative in only a finite region. We can increase $e$ so that it is always positive. Only $a,e>0$ for $x=0$ and $x\mapsto -\infty $

Answer (score 0):

$(x^2 - 1)^ 2 + 1  = x^4 - 2x^2 + 2 > 0$

Comment: You should add a few words to complement your answer.